# Convert inputbox data entry to cell data entry

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

I want to create a guessing game without using input boxes. I want the code to read my guesses on column A and then tell me if it was right or wrong in column C. The macro is for numbers 1 - 10 and the macro should go through each guess.

Here's my code -

```
Sub VBAGuessingGame()
Dim Secret As Integer
Dim Guess As Integer
Dim Tries As Integer

Randomize  'Initializes random-number generator

Secret = Int((10 * Rnd) + 1) 'Generates a random number between 1 and 10

Guess = 0
Tries = 0

Do While Guess <> Secret
    Guess = InputBox("Guess a number between 1 and 10.")
    If Guess = Secret Then
        Tries = Tries + 1
        MsgBox ("You guessed the number!")
        MsgBox ("It took you " & Tries & " to guess the number")

    ElseIf Guess > Secret Then
        Tries = Tries + 1
        MsgBox ("Wrong. Too high. Try again.")
    Else
        Tries = Tries + 1
        MsgBox ("Wrong. Too low. Try again.")
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to use public variables and the worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 0):

Put this behind Sheet1(Sheet1), if that's the sheet you're using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Guess As Integer, Secret As Integer
ThisColumn = Target.Column
ThisRow = Target.Row
If IsNumeric(Target.Cells.Value) Then
    Guess = Target.Cells.Value
Else: Guess = 0
End If
Randomize
Secret = Int(10 * Rnd) + 1

If ThisColumn = 1 Then
    If Guess = Secret Then
        Cells(ThisRow, 3).Value = "Right"
    Else
        Cells(ThisRow, 3).Value = "Wrong"
    End If
       Cells(ThisRow, 4).Value = Secret
End If
End Sub
```